# Laptop shuts down on boot

Tags: boot, laptop

My MEDION Akoya P6643 laptop started shutting down on boot today.

When I press the power button, it shows the MEDION logo, the fan starts to spin at high speeds (like it usually does when I play recent video games), then it shuts down.

The CPU doesn't have enough time to overheat (it is around 30°C when the laptop shuts down).

The heatsink is tightly screwed, and the thermal paste was changed a few days ago (when my laptop shut down as I was playing a 19 years old game). The laptop is also free of dust.

I have a laptop cooler, which is working fine (as my old laptop/media server doesn't get past 40°C with it, even when it does CPU intensive tasks).

When I enter the UEFI settings (using the F2 key on boot), the fan starts speeding up 5 seconds later. Input lag starts to appear. 5 seconds later, the laptop shuts down.

The laptop's warranty is over since almost one year, and I don't have the budget to buy a new laptop.

Thanks in advance for your answer(s).

Sorry for my English, I'm French.

Comment: Does this happen while on AC and DC power? So when plugged in/charging, as well as running off battery only.

Comment: It happens both when plugged in and on battery only.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the laptop plugged in, but removing the battery and trying to boot? Sometimes the pins on the battery can get loose and cause a bad ground. Try booting the battery removed

Comment: I followed [LSxCPU's instructions](http://superuser.com/questions/1019837/laptop-shuts-down-on-boot?noredirect=1#comment1416244_1019837), and it works. I'll try to order a new battery from MEDION to see if the problem persists. EDIT: The problem happened again. It seems there is an issue with the cooling on a software level, since the CPU and GPU are slightly above 30°C when the laptop turns off. EDIT 2: I removed the hard drive (like Carolina Eliz suggested), and it happens anyway.

Comment: Any bios update? Are fans coming in? Could also be an issue with the thermal paste between the core and the board

Comment: @LSxCPU According to MEDION, no BIOS updates are available. The fan is working, since it spins as soon as the laptop starts. I triple-checked the thermal paste, but there's no issues on that end (it's the same paste I used to replace my other laptop's).

Answer (score 0):

When you mentioned windows 7 I thought it's a newish machine and I've just checked out the model of your laptop it is quite old. I strongly believe it is a hard drive issue.

If you have access to a working hard drive from another working laptop, then it will confirm the theory. All you need to do is unscrew the panel from the underside of the laptop, hoping that will be the case because with some laptops you may need to undo the keyboard to get into the hard drive, then aput the hard drive you know is working, into it and if it boots up then you know you will have to replace the old hard drive and install whichever operating system you decide on.

Comment: I didn't mention the OS in the OP.

Comment: By the way, my laptop is less than 3 years old.